# how to display values in cell formula instead of references

Tags: vba, excel

I Have got some code to do this. But Iwant to customize this code is for my situation.
Current code:

```
Sub Finalone()
Dim lastrow As Long, r1 As Long
Dim temp As String, arTemp
Dim temp2 As String
Dim temp3 As String

temp3 = ""

    ' Get the last row in the worksheet
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For r1 = 1 To lastrow

    ' If A & B aren't blank, make the formula of cell C equal to A + B.
    If ActiveSheet.Range("$C$" & r1).Value <> "" And Mid(ActiveSheet.Range("$C$" & r1).Formula, 1, 1) = "=" Then
        If Asc(Mid(ActiveSheet.Range("$C$" & r1).Formula, 2, 1)) >= 65 And Asc(Mid(ActiveSheet.Range("$C$" & r1).Formula, 2, 1)) <= 90 Then
            ' Get the formula for the current C cell
            temp = Replace(ActiveSheet.Range("$C$" & r1).Formula, "=", "")

            ' Create an array by splitting the formula on the + sign
            arTemp = Split(temp, "+")

            temp2 = ActiveSheet.Range(arTemp(0)).Value

            For i = 1 To UBound(arTemp)
                temp3 = ActiveSheet.Range(arTemp(i)).Value

                temp2 = temp2 & "+" & temp3

            Next i

            ActiveSheet.Range("$C$" & r1).Value = "=" & temp2
        End If

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

The above code is work only for If A and B column has a value and C column has a formula and the formula is A+B.
But my siution is like- The values column may varry. The formula column is not C and the formula use for my situation is for example (R12-Q12)/2.
I need a macro to get input from user like the user has to select the column to convert above formula to values.

Comment: You can try: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-1]-RC[-2])/2"` Then all you need is a way to activate the macro

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But Actually I need to show the cell values in the formula not cell references. The above formula creates the cell reference.

Comment: Use offset...  `ActiveCell = (ActiveCell.Offset(, -1) - ActiveCell.Offset(, -2)) / 2`

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't support logical parsing of cells/numbers/operators in an easy way. I like a little challenge though, so I've knocked something togeher.

The below should work for you for parsing and recombining simple formulae using the 4 standard operators, brackets, numbers and cell references on the same sheet.

```
Sub FinalOne()

Dim rng As Range, rngPrecedents As Range, rngPrecedent As Range
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, x As Integer, b As Integer, rCount As Long
Dim tmp As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

'FIRST WE SET SOME VARIABLES FOR OUR ACTIVESHEET AND A TEMP SHEET TO HOLD THE PARSED FORMULAE
Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
Set ws2 = Sheets.Add
ws1.Activate
rCount = 1

'WE SET THE RANGE BASED ON USER SELECTION
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

'THEN WE ITERATE THROUGH EACH CELL
    For Each c In rng
        x = 1
        i = 0
        'AND THROUGH EACH CHARACTER ALONG THE LENGTH OF THE FORMULA
        For j = 1 To Len(c.Formula)
            Select Case Mid(c.Formula, j, 1)
                'WE CHECK IF THE GIVEN CHARACTER IS AN OPERATOR
                Case "=", "+", "-", "/", "*", "(", ")"
                    ws2.Range("A" & rCount).Offset(0, i).Value = Mid(c.Formula, j, 1)
                    i = i + 1
                'WE CHECK IF THE GIVEN CHARACTER IS A NUMERIC VALUE
                Case 0 To 9
                    ws2.Range("A" & rCount).Offset(0, i).Value = Mid(c.Formula, j, 1)
                    i = i + 1
                'OR WE ASSUME THAT IT'S A CELL REFERENCE
                Case Else
                    Set rngPrecedents = c.Precedents
                    Set rngPrecedent = rngPrecedents(x)
                    ws2.Range("A" & rCount).Offset(0, i).Value = rngPrecedent.Value
                    i = i + 1
                    j = j + Len(rngPrecedent.Address) - 3
                    x = x + 1
            End Select
        Next j
        rCount = rCount + 1
    Next c

'AFTER WE'VE PARSED THE CELL CONTENTS INTO DIFFERENT CELLS ON OUR TEMP SHEET
'WE RE-COMBINE THEM IN A TEMP COLUMN ON OUR WORKING SHEET

rng.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert

rCount = 1
i = 0

    For Each c In rng
        For i = 0 To ws2.Cells(rCount, ws2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            tmp = tmp + ws2.Range("A" & rCount).Offset(0, i).Text
        Next i
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = tmp
        tmp = ""
        rCount = rCount + 1
    Next c

'NOW WE TIDY UP

rng.Formula = rng.Offset(0, 1).Formula
rng.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ws2.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

If your references are off sheet, you may struggle as the precedents method only works with refs on the same sheet.

Comment: Forgot to mention. It doesn't handle using the same reference twice in the same formula well as it sees it as the same precedent. So `=(R12-Q12)/2` will work, but `=(R12-Q12)/R12` won't.